# An issue with the run configuration

Tags: c, gcc, mpi, eclipse-cdt, run-configuration

I have an issue with the Eclipse.

When I choose Generic MPICH2.... and local the option to choose connection is unclickable.

[image: Run configuration]

Comment: You are using an outdated Eclipse version. Please [upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades) and check if the issue still remains.

Comment: @howlger This does not help :(

Comment: Thanks for upgrading. Is the remote chooser disabled only for a _Generic MPICH2 Interactive_ target system configuration or for all (at least for [_Remote Generic Interactive_](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-03/topic/org.eclipse.ptp.doc.user/html/rms/remote-generic-interactive.html) it should be enabled)?

Comment: @howlger for all of them

Comment: I guess I misread your question. You say if you select _Local_, the drop-down and the _New_ button is disabled, right? Yes, this is the expected behavior. You have to choose _Remote_ even for a local application. In this context _Remote_ means, if I know right, a connection via IP which can also apply to local applications (at least this is the case for debugging Java applications).